# Lumen queue jobs with database drivers doesn't populate table jobs

Tags: queue, laravel-5.4, jobs, lumen, lumen-5.4

I'm completely new using laravel/lumen

I generate a new lumen proyect a few hours ago and I'm trying to send job to the default queue using a **database** driver.

my .env file looks like this

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=mydb
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=xxxx

CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=database
```

Following the official [Queues - Lumen](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues) page I generate a migration to create **jobs** and **failed_jobs** tables.

**config/queue.php** file has the default configuration

**Problem:**

1. before running the command `php artisan queue:work` I tried to send a job to the queue, `Queue::push(new SendEmailJob)` **but** it run immediately and I didn't run the command `php artisan queue:work` yet. 
   I check the database and table **job** is empty.
2. I run the command `php artisan queue:work` make a request to a specific endpoint, put the job on the queue using one of this line `Queue::push(new SendEmailJob)` or  `dispatch(new SendEmailJob())`
   I got no errors but **jobs** queue still empty

**What am I doing wrong?**

Why queue process all jobs before I run the command `php artisan queue:work` ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

1. You can dispatch a job and ask for a delay before it is executed:

> $this->dispatch((new ProcessJob($id))->delay(10)); // 10 ms

2. Make sure the worker is not running:

> ps aux|grep queue

If so, kill it. Although the best practice is to restart the worker after any code change:

> php artisan queue:restart

Comment: php artisan queue:work command is working, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

APP.PHP

if(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::hasTable("jobs"))
Queue::push(new ProcessCenterJob());

Answer (score 0):

For me it was the incorrect name for the driver/connection variable in the `.env` so it was still using `sync` instead of `database`. In the `.env` it was `QUEUE_DRIVER` but in the `queue.php` config it was referenced as `QUEUE_CONNECTION`

Rename the variable in `.env` to `QUEUE_CONNECTION` should resolve the issue